How can I decode Arbitrum SequencerInbox data in blob using nodejs?
Could someone explain please, what kind of data is stored in blobs of the "addSequencerL2BatchFromBlobs" transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x966508cb208f3f1dfff2999de2a26422dbc93a9a929dc472d0d43f47f0681fe1
And how can I decode this data using nodejs?
Thanks in advance!
